# Lazy loading caching mechanism

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, redis

I'm trying to build "smart" caching mechanism for my project. Short about project: it is social network, mostly read-intensive, plus there is websocket connection to nodejs for some realtime things - for example chat.

Is this a good way to build caching mechanism like this?
What pros and cons we got by using this method?

```
function loadUser($id) {
   $user_key = 'user_'.$id;

   if( $user = Zend_Registry::get($user_key)) ) {
      return $user;
   }
   elseif( $user = loadFromRedis($user_key) ) {
      Zend_Registry::set($user_key, $user);
   }
   else {
      $user = loadFromMysql($user_key)
      setToRedis($user_key, $user);
      setKeyExpire(30);
      Zend_Registry::set($user_key, $user);
   }

   return $user; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not the best way, because Zend adds a lot of overhead (and if you are caching is because you want to boost your application).

In this site there are many benchmarks explaining the Zend overhead (and comparissons with other frameworks): http://www.ruilog.com/blog/view/b6f0e42cf705.html

In my code I tend to use my own generic Model class, extend it with Models related with its connectors (MysqlModel, MongoModel, CassandraModel...), and extend those classes with classes directly related with the entities (UserModel, ArticleModel, ...) and write the cache handling code in the Model class, to reutilize it in the entire set of models.

The basic methods: readCache, writeCache, deleteCache. You can combine remote caches (like memcached or redis)  with local caches, like xcache or apc, to reduce the net overhead. But I recommend that local caches are used only if a certain flag is true, not by default.